# Move apps and games in Sony Xperia M to SD card

Tags: sd-card, app2sd, link2sd

How can I move apps and games in sony Xperia M? There is no `Move to SD card` option.

Answer (score 1):

To move my apps and games to my SD card I use the app [AppMgrIII](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd). I have had no issues so far.

Comment: A description and a use-case would definitely help since the answer, as of now, is not much worth without the link.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a rooted phone and a updated version of CM, I believe that in Settings -> Apps-> (on SD card) you will find a list with check-boxes.

But if you don't have CM, well, I recommend the app: [AppMgr III (App 2 SD)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd).